# Create graphene-django interface from models

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using graphene-django and i want to create four Interfaces, each representing models in Django, i'll start with only one model:

```
class TestInterface(graphene.Interface):
    items = graphene.Field(models.Test)
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'name'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `graphene.Field` should be a class that inherits from `DjangoObjectType` and *not* a Django model, e.g.

```
class TestType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
```